# Получить значение строкового тега в Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Посоветуйте, как лаконичнее всего получить значение строкового тега в Excel?
Специальной функции не нашел.

Пример

```
A1 = "tag1=123;tag2=abc;tag3=;"
```

Хочется получить

```
В1 = GetTagValue(A1;"tag2") = abc
```

Есть мудреное, длинное и некрасивое решение через FIND, MID, LEN... Есть что-то покороче?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такое. Теперь - есть )

**Функция пользователя (UDF)**

```
Function GetTagValue(sText As String, sTag As String, _
                    Optional sSym As String = ";") As String
Dim sStr As String
    sStr = Mid$(sText, InStr(sText, sTag))  ' отбрасываем левые тэги'
    sStr = Split(sStr, sSym)(0) ' отбрасываем правые тэги'
    GetTagValue = Replace(sStr, sTag & "=", "") ' оставляем значение тэга'
End Function
```

Код разместить в общем модуле.
В ячейке:

```
=GetTagValue(текст;тэг;[разделитель])
```

Опционально установлен разделитель *точка_с_запятой*. Если в тексте разделитель этот же, в формуле параметр можно не писать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
'------------------
```

**Формулой** с функциями листа - да, подлиннее будет:

```
=СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ЛЕВБ(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК(A2;A1)+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;99);";";ПОВТОР(" ";99));99))
```

Если использовать вспомогательную ячейку (*B2*), можно упростить:

```
B2 =ПСТР(A1;ПОИСК(A2;A1)+ДЛСТР(A2)+1;99)
B1 =ЛЕВБ(B2;ПОИСК(";";B2)-1)
```

Comment: спасибо! Работает. Cкажите, пожалуйста, а есть ли способ вызвать эту функцию из персональной книги макросов не упоминая её? Т.е. набирать не "=PERSONAL.XLSB!GetTagValue(A1;A2)" а просто "=GetTagValue(A1;A2)" , в любой книге Excel?

Comment: Создать новую книгу,  разместить в общем модуле функцию, сохранить книгу как надстройку (.xlam). Подключить надстройку

Comment: спасибо большое, все получилось. :)